# apache storm topology id skips from n to n+2

Tags: deployment, apache-storm

We are using apache-storm-0.9.6 on a cluster of 1 nimbus node + 4 supervisor nodes.

During this weekend, the topology named `fetcher-10-1459843589` suddenly stopped processing any message. It was `ACTIVE`, everything seemed up and running, but no data was processed.

Finally, we've manually restarted the topology. And the new topology is named `fetcher-12-1460363279`. It runs ok, it processes data.

**QUESTION** -->
We do not understand why we step from **fetcher-10-...** to **fetcher-12-...**? **Where could be fetcher-11-...?**

Actually we do not understand many things, but we hope this will help us :). What we really want to find is why do we get these freeze states, when the topology is `ACTIVE`, there is no reported exception, and no data is processed.

Please note that Storm is launched in a docker. Should you need more information, let me know. I will edit this post.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I've found the answer.

In a cluster there may be more topologies running.

Let `A`, `B`, `C`, `D` be 4 topologies running in the same cluster. It was my case. When you start the topologies they will have assigned **consecutive numbers not per topology, but per cluster** (that was my error). Thus we start with:

```
A-1-...
B-2-...
C-3-...
D-4-...
```

If you restart `C`, you'll have

```
C-5...
```

So where is `C-4`? It simply does not exists, because the `4` is already taken by `D`.

Thus, it is normal to skip from `n` yo `n+2`. You may find `n+1` assigned to another topology. (q.e.d.)